# WinForms MDI form smooth switch between child forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a MDI parent form

> formMain

I use the form to display 2 different child forms inside it.

> formChildOne, formChildTwo

The problem is that whenever I switch between the child forms, the interface gets really jittery until the form is fully shown and it looks ugly as hell.

How can I make the process look a little more elegant?

Comment: Some screenshot maybe ?

Comment: Tends to happen when you always keep the MDI child window maximized.  Only one of them can be maximized, so when you switch then you'll see it restoring the old one, selecting the new one and maximizing it.  If the forms don't resize smoothly then that looks pretty "jittery".  Just don't use MDI if that's your preferred UI, swap docked user controls instead.

Comment: What does `jittery` mean? The size changes? The form freezes? Something else? If there was such an issue with Winforms itself people would have noticed from the start - 17 years ago. If `jittery` means "the control sizes keep changing" it probably means that the form code and layout change as data gets loaded.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What I mean by jittery is that the size change of the forms and controls within the form are really noticeable and it just doesn't look good

Comment: @bapster fixed-size controls don't move around. This means the controls were configured to change size while loading data or other controls. If you use fixed-size controls, they wouldn't change. You could also use docking or a layout manager, minimum sizes etc to reduce the need for resizing. WIthout the form code though, one can only guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set this property on your Child forms and parent form:

```
DoubleBuffered=True
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think that's `true` by default

Comment: It's true by default. From [How to: Reduce Graphics Flicker with Double Buffering for Forms and Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-reduce-graphics-flicker-with-double-buffering-for-forms-and-controls) : `Standard Windows Forms controls are double buffered by default.`

Comment: I've already tried it and it reduced the "jittery feeling" but not totally

Comment: No for Windows Forms default value is = false, anyway he can check and see if it helps 

Comment: It didn't - it's the *controls* that change size, and as the docs explain, for the controls double buffering is enabled by default

Comment: But he is asking for forms not for controls - I'm not sure there is any other way to remove the flickering - it may dependent if you have much code on form activated event.. maybe huge data load? @bapster try to create an new project with empty child forms?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos It's not *enabled by default*, actually. *DoubleBuffering is enabled...* means that the feature is present, not that is active. You have to enable it (as also described two lines down in the Docs) setting `DoubleBuffered = true`. Where this property can be found. Some controls do not expose the property, the Style must be set in a derived class (the Panel control, for example). A few more lines down, one can find the [How to: Manually Manage Buffered Graphics](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-manually-manage-buffered-graphics)

Comment: @Jimi tha'ts the advanced scenarios page. The *previous* page explains that it is enabled by default. I copied the exact quote. Both pages come from the very same section in the docs

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Nope, it explains that the feature is enabled, not that it's active: *Windows Forms controls are double buffered by default. **You can enable default double buffering in your forms and authored controls in two ways** (...)*. Meaning, the [BufferedGraphicsContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bufferedgraphicscontext) is managed, you just need to say you want to use it. Easy to test, drawing on a control's surface with and without `DoubleBuffered = true`. PictureBox and Flat Label enable this featue automatically.

Comment: @bapster at least it helped a little?

Comment: @DevFlamur Just as I said before, I've already tried it and it reduced the jitter, but it's not completly gone

Comment: @bapster have you tried with an new project with empty child forms?

Comment: @DevFlamur Yeah I've tried it and it was a little better. I managed to play a little with my code and reducded the flickering as much as I could. Thank you for your help everyone

Comment: @bapster then mark an answer so it may help the others